# This expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated.... Acces 2003 issues

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I have a query that I get this error on when I am typing mismatching dates.  For example, if my date range is 1/1/2014 - 3/1/2014 it works fine.  If I change the date range to 1/31/2014 - 2/28/2014 I get this error.  As long as the days are the same number it works.  I am completely stumped.  Any ideas?  Here is the query I am using:

```
PARAMETERS [START DATE] DateTime, [END DATE] DateTime;
SELECT DISTINCT VEHICLE.VID, VEHICLE.VLOCATION, FUELTRAN.TRANDATE,

(SELECT FUELTRAN.ODOMETER
FROM FUELTRAN
 WHERE VEHICLE.VID = FUELTRAN.VID
 AND (TRANDATE BETWEEN [START DATE] AND [END DATE])
 AND TRANID = (SELECT MAX(TRANID)
 FROM FUELTRAN
 WHERE VEHICLE.VID = FUELTRAN.VID
 AND (TRANDATE BETWEEN [START DATE] AND [END DATE])
 AND FUELTRAN.ODOMETER > 0)) AS CURRENTODOM,

 (SELECT FUELTRAN.ODOMETER
 FROM FUELTRAN
 WHERE VEHICLE.VID = FUELTRAN.VID
 AND (TRANDATE BETWEEN [START DATE] AND [END DATE])
 AND TRANID = (SELECT MIN(TRANID)
 FROM FUELTRAN
 WHERE VEHICLE.VID = FUELTRAN.VID
 AND (TRANDATE BETWEEN [START DATE] AND [END DATE])
 AND FUELTRAN.ODOMETER > 0)) AS INITIALODOM,


 (SELECT SUM(FUELTRAN.GALLONS)
 FROM FUELTRAN
 WHERE FUELTRAN.VID = VEHICLE.VID
 AND (TRANDATE BETWEEN [START DATE] AND [END DATE])) AS TOTALGALLONS,
 ((CURRENTODOM-INITIALODOM)/TOTALGALLONS) AS MPG


 FROM VEHICLE, FUELTRAN
WHERE VEHICLE.VID=FUELTRAN.VID And TRANDATE=[END DATE] And (VEHICLE.VTYPE="STRAIGHT TRUCK" Or VEHICLE.VTYPE="TRACTOR")
ORDER BY VEHICLE.VLOCATION, VEHICLE.VID, FUELTRAN.TRANDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a simpler query such as :

```
PARAMETERS STARTDATE DateTime, ENDDATE DateTime;
SELECT VEHICLE.VID, VEHICLE.VLOCATION, VEHICLE.VTYPE, Sum(FUELTRAN.GALLONS) AS TOTALFUEL,
Max([ODOMETER])-Min([ODOMETER]) AS MILAGE, [MILAGE]/[TOTALFUEL] AS MPG
FROM FUELTRAN INNER JOIN VEHICLE ON FUELTRAN.VID = VEHICLE.VID
WHERE (((FUELTRAN.TRANDATE) Between [STARTDATE] And [ENDDATE]))
GROUP BY VEHICLE.VID, VEHICLE.VLOCATION, VEHICLE.VTYPE
HAVING (((VEHICLE.VTYPE)="STRAIGHT TRUCK" Or (VEHICLE.VTYPE)="TRACTOR"));
```

had similar problems in the past when using multiple subqueries.